# usb storage media do not mount anymore

Tags: usb-drive

I have been using Elementary OS for one year and everything worked fine till last Friday (May 17 2019).
Now, when I plug a usb key or usb hard-disk, the media does not mount.
What has been changed in Elementary and how can I go back to the previous configuration?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oops, the problem was not coming from Elementary but... from Windows.
I mounted the device manually with sudo mount and it says:
The disk contains an unclean file system (0,0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on windows. Fixing.

It was the same problem for both my usb-key and my hard-disk.
Now everything works fine as before.